# Create a Laravel Request object on the fly

Tags: php, request, laravel-5.1

I'm handling data in one controller and want to pass it further into another controller to avoid duplicate code.

Is there a way to set up a Request object that is needed in the other controller's `store`-method? I've traced down the Request inheritance and came to Symfony's Request object which has a `request` property that is in fact a `ParameterBag` that holds a method `add` to add parameters with values to it.

I've tried the following but I'm getting `null` as result:

```
$myRequest = new Request();
$myRequest->request->add(['foo' => 'bar']);
var_dump($myRequest->foo);
```

I'm on Laravel 5.1 for this project.

Comment: To "avoid duplicate code you" you need to abstract the common functionality into a dedicated class, give it a proper mnemonic name, write a set of unit tests around it, and then mock it in controllers when unittesting controllers.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();

$request->replace(['foo' => 'bar']);

dd($request->foo);
```

Alternatively, it would make more sense to create a `Job` for whatever is going on in your second controller and remove the `ShouldQueue` interface to make it run synchronously.

Comment: Thanks, due to a time limit I have solved it with a little duplicate code (other things had to happen in the outside-controller as well). I'll remember this for another time!

Comment: can you tell me how we can change the request method to `POST` ?

Comment: @RahulSharma you can do by this way  ::  Request::create(' any URL that you want to 
 add here ','POST',['title'=>'New Article Published.','body' =>$post->title]);

Answer (score 53):

Creating a request object with `$myRequest = new Request();` creates the object with `method = 'GET'`. You can check your request's method with `$myRequest->getMethod()`.
As the `request` property holds data for POST requests you cannot use `$myRequest->request->add()` by default. First you have to set the request's method to POST:

```
$myRequest = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$myRequest->setMethod('POST');
$myRequest->request->add(['foo' => 'bar']);
dd($request->foo);
```

By the way using `$myRequest->query->add()` you can add data to a GET request.

Answer (score 44):

To "avoid duplicate code" you need to abstract the common functionality into a dedicated class, give it a proper mnemonic name, write a set of unit tests around it, and then mock it in controllers when unittesting controllers.

but if you still need to make requests:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$request = new Request([
        'name'   => 'unit test',
        'number' => 123,
    ]);
```

and if you need the full functionality of the Request, you need to add some extra lines

```
$request
    ->setContainer(app())
    ->setRedirector(app(\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::class))
    ->validateResolved();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the existing request and fill it with new data:

```
$request = (clone request())->replace(['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

this

```
$myRequest = new Request();
$myRequest->request->add(['foo' => 'bar']);
var_dump($myRequest->foo);
```

to

```
$myRequest = new Request();
$myRequest->merge(['foo' => 'bar']);
echo $myRequest->input('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the request parameter on the fly using these methods.

## Replace

[replace function doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_replace)

If you are in controller then, pass Request object in paramter of the function like

```
  function createUser(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
     $request->replace(array_merge(array("new_key1"=>"new_value1","new_key_n"=>"new_value_n"), $request->all()));
}
```

## Merge function

[merge function doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge)

```
function createUser(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
     $request->merge(array("new_key1"=>"new_value1","new_key_n"=>"new_value_n"));
}
```

## add function

```
 function createUser(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
     $request->request->add(array_merge(array("new_key1"=>"new_value1","new_key_n"=>"new_value_n"), $request->all()));
}
```

Note:: in all function we are extending the request, mean previous parameter will remain there. You will be adding your own. You can replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all other solutions but no one was working on my side. so Tried a new Soution that is working in my case. It will be useful if you are looking at **Randow or New URL**. it will not update your existing $request parameters.

```
 Request::create('URL that you want ','POST',['title'=>'New Article Published.','body' =>$post->title]);
```

Check the response on the Log File.

[image]