# How to Use custom request (make:request)? (laravel) Method App\Http\Requests\Custom::doesExistI does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-request

I created a custom request to make my own validation. As i follow these [article](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#validation).

I created **ProfileRequest**

```
php artisan make:request ProfileRequest
```

Inside my **ProfileRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:10',
            'age' => 'required|numeric'
        ]; 
    }
}
```

---

My problem is when I use the **ProfileRequest** inside the controller, like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function update(ProfileRequest $request){
        return "123";
    }
}
```

It returns an error like these below:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\ProfileRequest does not exist
```

I need your help Sirs. Somebody know how to use the custom request?

Comment: @PrinceKumarDwivedi Sir it returns an error Class App\Http\Controllers\ProfileRequest does not exist. And bdw the ProfileRequest I made is a request stored in App/Http/Requests/

Comment: Sorry its my mistake use  App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest; try this is the correct.

Comment: it returns error sir `Class App\Http\ProfileRequest does not exist`

Comment: Check my link for your Answer .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78189546/4335210

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **ProfileRequest** change `extends FormRequest` to `extends Request`. Then add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` above the class. Code should look like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:10',
            'age' => 'required|numeric'
        ]; 
    }
}
```

Then put `App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest;` in your controller.

Comment: I did it but returns an error Sir `Class 'App\Http\Requests\Request' not found`

Comment: Also add ```use Illuminate\Http\Request;``` on top of ProfileRequest

Answer (score 2):

create ProfileRequest

```sh
php artisan make:request Profile/ProfileRequest
```

inside ProfileRequest

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Profile;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProfileUpdate extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
         return [
            'name' => 'required|min:10',
            'age' => 'required|numeric'
        ]; 
    }
}
```

Then put use `App\Http\Requests\Profile\ProfileRequest` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest` in your controller

like: `use App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest`

then try: `composer dumpautoload`, `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Sir it returns an error `Class App\Http\Controllers\ProfileRequest does not exist`. And bdw the `ProfileRequest` I made is a request stored in `App/Http/Requests/`

Comment: I tried Sir but returns an error like this `Method App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest::doesExistI does not exist.` can you check the codes of my `ProfileRequest` Sir for me. thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

You have to import `ProfileRequest` instead of `Request` on your controller,

just this:

```
use App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest;
```

Comment: Sir it returns an error `Method App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest::doesExistI does not exist.` can you check the code of my `ProfileRequest` Sir, I think the problem is in there, I'm not sure

Comment: can you please add your full `ProfileController` class and `ProfileRequest` class here?

Comment: that is my full `ProfileController` Sir

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,
First of all You have to import request in your controller,

```
use App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest;


 $validated = $request->validated();
        if ($validated) {
             // ...
         }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sir it returns an error `Method App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest::doesExistI does not exist.`. I think the problem is in the `ProfileRequest` codes Sir

Comment: I observe Sir in the article **Good**, the custom request extends a request. Can you check it for me Sir. thanks for response

Comment: Actually I implemented  it with FormRequest, at that time i dont know it with request, No problem, thank you for that tutorial. You can check it with `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I tried `composer dump-autoload` but still returns this error `Method App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest::doesExistI does not exist.` I really don't know what's wrong with this.

Comment: Tried `php artisan cache:clear` but still returns the same error :(

Comment: try with `new ProfileRequest` in method parameter

Comment: error Sir `syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: Something freaky

Answer (score 0):

In your ProfileRequest.php 
change

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Http\FormRequest;
```

And then just

```
php artisan config:cache 
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: Sir it returns `Class 'Illuminate\Http\FormRequest' not found`

Comment: did u cahnged the 'use Illuminate\Http\Request;' to 'use Illuminate\Http\FormRequest;' in your controller ?

Comment: I changed but this another error returns `Class App\Http\Controllers\ProfileRequest does not exist`

Comment: add this in the top of your controller 'namespace App\Http\Controllers;'

Comment: yes Sir I have that `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` in my controller