# How to use custom requests on Laravel 9 (php artisan make:request CreateCarRequest)

Tags: php, laravel, http, validation

i'm trying to use **custom requests in laravel** but i can't find bug. I have read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation) and many tutorials in english and spanish.

I created the class **CreateCarRequest** with

```
php artisan make:request CreateCarRequest
```

`

My CreateCarRequest.php looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateCarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // TODO autorizaion logic
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'plate' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:cars,plate',
            'brand' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'model' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'seats' => 'required|integer|min:0', // TODO discuss min 0 or 1?
            'fuel' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'priceRent' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'smoke' => 'required|boolean',
            'pet' => 'required|boolean',
            'airConditioner' => 'required|boolean',
            'parkSensor' => 'required|boolean',
            'bluetooth' => 'required|boolean'
        ];
    }
}
```

The controller **CarsController.php** where i try to use it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateCarRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\EditCarRequest;
use App\Models\Car;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CarsController extends Controller {
    public function show() {
        $cars = Car::paginate(10);
        return view('cars.adminCars', ['cars' => $cars ]);
    }

    public function create() {
        return view('cars.adminCarCreate');
    }

    public function confirmCreate(CreateCarRequest $request): RedirectResponse {
        Log::info('IN CONFIRM CREATE FUNCTION'); // debugging
        $validatedData = $request->validated();
        Log::info($validatedData);
        return redirect()->action([CarsController::class, "create"]);
    }

}
```

My problem is it never gets inside **confirmCreate**. I use logs to know it and it never writes anything in the log file.

Has somebody faced this problem or can help me ? Thanks in advance.

P.D. I have already tried all proposed solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631139/how-to-use-custom-request-makerequest-laravel-method-app-http-requests-cus) but no one has helped me.

Comment: How/where do you call `confirmCreate`? Anything in your logs? Most likely your form request validation fails and you don't show any validation messages

Comment: The route of the create car form is asociated with confirmCreate. The route code: Route::post('/admin/cars/create', [CarsController::class, 'confirmCreate'])
    ->name('car.create.save');

Comment: What the point to use route confirm which then call other method? not good practice

Comment: So do you have validation/error messages inside your form?

Comment: @InDevX i have two routes: car.create (GET) to get the form and car.create.save(POST) to send the form and do all the validations. I'm following guidelines of my university teacher.

Comment: @brombeer no, it never gets inside confirmCreate when the parameter is CreateCarRequest $request. I've tried to change to normal Request and it works but i want to use custom requests.

Comment: It'll get to confirmCreate when the CreateCarRequest is valid.

Comment: i don't get any validation errors. Laravel uses the rules on his own ? I thought i have to use request->validator() method to check the rules.

Comment: You don't have to check the rules, your form data will already be validated when it gets to the controller. You use `$validated = $request->validated();` to use the (already) validated data. If it doesn't get to the controller most likely your validation failed. How do you know you don't get validation errors when you don't have validation/error messages inside your form? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: @ErikAvagyan then u should redirect to route (smth like `redirect()->route('route_name')`) which lead to car.create (GET) form, not for method.

Comment: What's going on when u trying to create car? U press buttom on form and what goes?

Comment: @brombeer thank you, the problem was in the validation rules. The checkbox inputs were required and the guy who implemented this didn't show the errors. Thank you again.

Comment: @ErikAvagyan what you could do is answer your own question with brombeer's solution. That way it marks this question as answered.