# Laravel working with a new instance from a custom request ignores validators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to build a custom Artisan command with Laravel, this one can create a product by custom request and pass it to the controller to ensure that validators work fine. on the web, everything works fine, but when I run my custom command with an **EMPTY** field, the validators don't work and I get the integrity constraint violation error.

This is my custom command code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ProductController;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CreateProduct extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'product:create';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create new product';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $productName = $this->ask("Product name");
        $productDescription = $this->ask("Product description");
        $productPrice = $this->ask("Product price");
        $productImageUrl = $this->ask("Product image url");

//        $productRequest = new ProductRequest([
//            "name" => $productName,
//            "description" => $productDescription,
//            "price" => $productPrice,
//            "image" => $productImageUrl
//        ]);
//        $productRequest->setMethod('POST');
//        $productRequest->replace(['foo' => 'bar']);

        $productController = app()->make(ProductController::class);
        $response = $productController->store(
            new ProductRequest([
                "name" => $productName,
                "description" => $productDescription,
                "price" => $productPrice,
                "image" => $productImageUrl
            ])
        );
        $this->info($response);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This my custom request code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "name" => "required|string|min:3|max:255",
            "description" => "required",
            "price" => "required",
            "image" => "required|string|max:2048",
            'categories.*' => "exists:categories,id"
        ];
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'success'   => false,
            'message'   => 'Validation errors',
            'data'      => $validator->errors()
        ]));
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            "name.required" => "The name of product is mandatory",
            "description.required" => "The description of product is mandatory",
            "price.required" => "The price of product is mandatory",
            "image.required" => "The image of product is mandatory",
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->productRepository->all();
        return response()->json($products);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    public function store(ProductRequest $productRequest)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->create($productRequest->only(['name', 'description', 'price', 'image', 'categories']));
        return response()->json($product);
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $productUpdated = $this->productRepository->update($request->only(['name', 'description', 'price', 'image']), $id);
        return response()->json($productUpdated);
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $deleted = $this->productRepository->delete($id);
        return response()->json([$deleted]);
    }

    public function filterProductsByCategory($id) {
        $products = $this->productRepository->filterProductsByCategory($id);
        return response()->json($products);
    }
}
```

Comment: you would need to resolve your FormRequest from the service container, not creating a new isntance yourself. The Formrequest wont be filled with any request data and it won't validate by itself; these are things the service container does when resolving these requests ... if you don't resolve it from the container you would have to call a factory method on the request to create it from the current app request and then you would have to call the validation method needed to validate the request

Comment: @lagbox Can u give an example, please? I need to use my custom request so can u show me how to do it with the service container

Comment: `app(ProductRequest::class)`

Comment: @lagbox and how can I pass data, because when I declare it like this, it generates error validation at the execution of this line, so I need to add data to it before executing it.

Comment: if there is no incoming request, which is the case here as it is a command, you will have to get an instance yourself and then replace the inputs or merge the inputs then call the vlaidation: `$r = new YourRequest; $r->replace(['key' => 'value', ...]); $r->validateResolved();`

Comment: @lagbox validateResolved() method generates this error "  Call to a member function call() on null"

Comment: would need more than just that, as that error doesn't say where it is coming from .... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9203fca96960ef9cd8860cb4ec99d1279353a8d/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php#L36   that is what you have to do if you get an instance of the FormRequest yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246660/discussion-between-reda-taha-and-lagbox).

Comment: ibb.co/NyY7gBq this is the full error

Comment: Check my link for your Answer .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78189546/4335210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge data into the Request that is bound to the Container, which is what gets used to create the FormRequest from:

```
$request = app('request');
$request->replace(['your' => 'data', ...]); // or merge([...])
```

Then you can ask the Container for an instance of your FormRequest (which it does things to when resolving to fill it and validate it):

```
$productController->store(app(YourRequestClass::class));
```

Ideally you would not be calling a Controller like this, instead using the Container to call the method for you, so it will do dependency injection for you:

```
$response = app()->call('YourController@method');
```

Though you should really refactor this code out of the Controller and put it somewhere that your Controller and Command can both makes call to it.

Comment: This works, Can u show me please how can I show messages in info?

Comment: Because now it shows all the exception error

Comment: you would have to catch the exception and do what you want at that point